# Cant Update CLLocation() from user Location SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Hello I’m really new to iOS and `SwiftUi` so don't hate me if my formatting is wrong haha. I’m having trouble converting the users location coordinates to a US address. I have gotten most of the code done but for some reason on line `109` I create the `@Published var location` and set it to some random location and then I try to update it on line `l72` but for some reason it just uses the first location I pass in on line `109`. Id love for this to update and use the users current location after they grant permission. Thanks you for any suggestions you have :)

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Parked
//
//  Created by Luke Jamison on 11/2/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI

struct ContentView: View {
    static let sharedV = ContentView()
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    
    @State var addressData: String = ""
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    //@State var geo: Any = locationManager.location
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
                    .onAppear {
                        viewModel.checkIFLocationServicesisEnabled()
                        setData()
                        //viewModel.runSetDatafunc()
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).cornerRadius(20).padding()
                
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Add Location Details")) {
                        Text(addressData)
                        Menu {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showingImagePicker = true
                            }) {
                                Label("Take Picture", systemImage: "camera.shutter.button")
                            }
                            image?.resizable()
                                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                                .shadow(radius: 10)
                            
                            
                        } label: {
                            Label("Add Image", systemImage: "photo.on.rectangle.angled")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    if image != nil {
                        Section(header: Text("Image Taken")) {
                            ZStack {
                                Rectangle().fill(Color.secondary)
                                
                                if image != nil {
                                    image?.resizable().scaledToFit()
                                } else {
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            Button(action: {
                                image = nil
                            }) {
                                Label("Remove Picture", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                    ImagePicker(image: self.$inputImage)
                    
                }.navigationBarTitle("Parked", displayMode: .automatic)
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        
    }
    func setData() {
        ContentViewModel.shared.resolveLoactionName(with: viewModel.location) { [self] locationName in
            self.addressData = locationName
        }
    }
    
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        static let shared = ContentViewModel()
        
        @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.4, longitude: -117.4), span:
                                                    MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        
        
        @Published var address = ""
        @Published var location = CLLocation.init(latitude: 33, longitude: -117)
        
        var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
        
        func checkIFLocationServicesisEnabled() {
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager!.delegate = self
                //locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            } else {
                print("this is off turn in the settings...")
            }
        }
        
        public func resolveLoactionName(with location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
            
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: .current) { placemarks, error in
                guard let place = placemarks?.first, error == nil else {
                    completion("")
                    return
                }
                print(place)
                var name = ""
                
                if let locality = place.subThoroughfare {
                    name += locality
                }
                
                if let street = place.thoroughfare {
                    name += " \(street)"
                }
                
                if let city = place.locality {
                    name += " \(city)"
                }
                
                if let adminRegion = place.administrativeArea {
                    name += ", \(adminRegion)"
                }
                
                if let zipCode = place.postalCode {
                    name += " \(zipCode)"
                }
                
                completion(name)
            }
        }
        
         private func checkLocationAuth() {
            guard let locationManager = locationManager else { return }
            
            switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
                
            case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            case .restricted:
                print("location is restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("location is denied in settings for app")
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
                ContentView.sharedV.setData()
                self.location = CLLocation(latitude: region.self.center.latitude, longitude: region.self.center.longitude)
                print(location)
                //runSetDatafunc()
                //address = "\(locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude), \(locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)"
                /*geocode(latitude: region.center.latitude, longitude: region.center.longitude) { placemark, error in
                    let placemark = placemark?.first
                    //print(placemark?.description)
                    //self.address = "\(placemark?.thoroughfare), \(placemark?.locality), \(placemark?.administrativeArea)"
                }*/
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
            
        }
        public func runSetDatafunc() {
           
        }
        func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
            checkLocationAuth()
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are a bit all over the place here;  You have a shared "singleton" instance of your view model; Don't do that.  You have a shared instance of your view.  Definitely don't do that; SwiftUI views are structs and empheral.  They are recreated each time the view updates.  You are requesting "when in use" but checking for "always" location authentication.  Getting location is an asynchronous operation; so you need to request location or call `startUpdatingLocation` and handle the location update in the delegate method.

Comment: If you do call `startUpdatingLocation` you will get updates once every second or so.  Sending requests to reverse geocoding at this rate will result in failures because this service is rate limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the transient nature of SwiftUI views, you definitely won't have luck making a singleton out of a `View`. But, you don't need it because you're already publishing your `region` and `location`, which your `View` will update in reaction to.

Here's a simplified/refactored version of your code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.address)
            Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.checkIfLocationServicesisEnabled()
                }
        }
    }
}

final class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = ContentViewModel()
    
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.4, longitude: -117.4), span:
                                                MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    @Published var address = ""
    @Published var location = CLLocation.init(latitude: 33, longitude: -117)
    
    private var lastResolved : CLLocation = .init()
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    func checkIfLocationServicesisEnabled() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            //locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        } else {
            print("this is off turn in the settings...")
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let last = locations.last else { return }
        
        if last.distance(from: lastResolved) > 200 {
            resolveLocationName(with: last) { address in
                self.address = address
                self.lastResolved = last
            }
        }
        
        self.location = last
    }
    
    public func resolveLocationName(with location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
        
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: .current) { placemarks, error in
            guard let place = placemarks?.first, error == nil else {
                completion("")
                return
            }
            print(place)
            var name = ""
            
            if let locality = place.subThoroughfare {
                name += locality
            }
            
            if let street = place.thoroughfare {
                name += " \(street)"
            }
            
            if let city = place.locality {
                name += " \(city)"
            }
            
            if let adminRegion = place.administrativeArea {
                name += ", \(adminRegion)"
            }
            
            if let zipCode = place.postalCode {
                name += " \(zipCode)"
            }
            
            completion(name)
        }
    }
    
    private func checkLocationAuth() {
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else { return }
        
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
            
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("location is restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("location is denied in settings for app")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location!.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
            self.location = CLLocation(latitude: region.self.center.latitude, longitude: region.self.center.longitude)
            print(location)
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        checkLocationAuth()
    }
}
```

Note that I'm calling `startUpdatingLocation()` and implementing `didUpdateLocations` -- these will allow you to get/update the user's location.

In the simulator, you can use the Features->Location menu to simulate different spots. You'll see it resolve different spots and show the address at the top of the screen.

Comment: It is a bad idea to call `reverseGeocodeLocation` from `didUpdateLocations` without guarding for a reasonable movement; You will trip over the rate limiting

Comment: Good point -- updated with a location constraint and will add a note to the OP in the answer.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you so much! the only issue I’m seeing is that `Cannot find 'lastResolved' in scope`

Comment: @Luke sorry -- I had updated one part and not the other and forgot to add the property. See updated version.

Comment: @jnpdx I see it thank you so so much!!

Comment: @Luke If this answered the question, can you use the green check mark to mark it as correct?